# Locally disable "Treat Warnings As Error" configuration in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am working with the option "Treat Warnings As Error" enabled in Visual Studio 2019.
The are some portions in the code I want to disable this option for - in such a way that there will still be a warning, but it will not be treated as an error. I was hoping there is some #pragma I can use for this purpose.

I am aware of #pragma warning(disable : N) which can be used to completely eliminate the warning report, but I still want to see the warning, just don't want the compilation to fail for that particular chunk of code. Of course, in other places it should produce an error upon warning, as expected.

Comment: That is an interesting problem - why do you need that?

Comment: As a workaround: As long as you can separate the code into separate folders, you can use a globalconfig/editorconfig in that folder (and everything below it) to reduce the warning level to info for the warnings.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify the code paths. I have a very large codebase, given as is. As for the reason I need this - the option of "Treat Warnings As Error" is something we want to use in our codebase, but there are some warnings which seem to be more troublesome to resolve, so we want to temporarily allow the code to still be compilable,   but still show these warnings as regular warnings (as a reminder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (From the comments): The option of "Treat Warnings As Error" is something we want to use in our codebase, but there are some warnings which seem to be more troublesome to resolve, so we want to temporarily allow the code to still be compilable, but still show these warnings as regular warnings (as a reminder)

I do not believe the thing you ask for in the question is possible.

Luckily, the thing you say you want, and the thing you ask for, is not the same.

MSVC exposes the `#pragma message( message-string )` option [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/message?view=msvc-170)

First, enable warning-as-error.

Next, for the warnings you cannot get rid of today, do `#pragma warning(disable : N)` like you already know, and *at the same time* use `# pragma message (__FILE__ "[" STRING(__LINE__) "]: WARNING HERE")` or whatever message suits your use case.

This will allow you to compile with warnings-as-errors to prevent future warnings *and* retain your reminder of the current problem spots.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution that fits my needs